# How do i use getIntent().getSerializableExtra to retrieve data from the database

Tags: java, android, firebase

i passed data from one activity to another and found this way to retrieve my get methods from my Shop class.

now i do not know how to proceed to insert these data into the TextViews or ImageViews in my DetailsActivity.

how would i go about doing this?

this is my code so far:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private RecyclerView FirestoreList;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    TextView name_details;
    TextView address_details;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);


        Shop shopModel = (Shop) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("shopModel");



        name_details = findViewById(R.id.details_shopName);
        address_details = findViewById(R.id.detail_addressDetails);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `setText` method with your `TextView`

```
name_details.setText(shopModel.yourNameValue());
address_details.setText(shopModel.yourAddressValue());
```

With `ImageView` is a little bit complicate if your image is from Internet. You need a image downloading library like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

or if your image is from `res/drawable`, you just need to

```
imageView.setImageResource(shopModel.yourImageResId());
```

Comment: thank you so much, i am novice in java. your help is much appreciated!